# Intellij: No usages found in Project Files

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, intellij-15

I'm using IntelliJ 15 and I'm trying to find usages of methods and objects in a .java file packed in a .jar file downloaded through Maven. I now that they're used: I can find them through the simple `search` (ctrl+f) command, but when I try with the `Find Usages` command the post-title message is returned.

I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27634694/intellij-ultimate-14-find-usages-not-working) post, but it doesn't work.

This an example of a method in a file `InstanceManager.class` (belonging to .jar file imported with Maven):

```
private void notifyNewInstance(Instance instance) {
    List var2 = this.instanceListeners;
    synchronized(this.instanceListeners) {
        Iterator var3 = this.instanceListeners.iterator();

        while(var3.hasNext()) {
            InstanceListener listener = (InstanceListener)var3.next();

            try {
                listener.newInstanceAvailable(instance);
            } catch (Throwable var7) {
                LOG.error("Notification of new instance availability failed.", var7);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

And in the same file is called with `this.notifyNewInstance(host);` but if I use `Find usages` on `notifyNewInstance` I'll receive the error.

**UPDATE:**
I've tried to `Download` the source code, but I get the message:

> Cannot download sources Sources not found for:
>   org.apache.flink:flink-runtime_2.10:1.1-20160316.114232-35

Can you help me with that?

Comment: What type of usage is there? Could it be that there are multiple classes with the same name on your classpath (but with different package names)? Have you tried ticking all the boxes when doing advanced usage search (ctrl+shift+alt+F7)?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "type of usage", but for example in find of usage of a method, I would like to see a list of where the method is called, and this doesn't happen (even if I KNOW that it does even in the same file).

Comment: Is the `.jar` you downloaded a dependency? If so, it's not a usage in your Project Files because it's read as a dependency by IntelliJ. Can you also provide code and/or examples of what you're doing as it is unclear.

Comment: Updated with example

Comment: That method is decompiled from a class file... It isn't part of the class file. You have to download the sources of the Maven library if you want to search the methods

Comment: You're right. I **UPDATED** the question

Comment: Possibly useful note: IntelliJ considers the version for "find usages", so if you have two different libraries (A and B) loaded in your project, and A depends on B-2.10, if you release B-2.10 and then start working on B-2.11 in the same project while A still depends on B-2.10, then IntelliJ will start reporting that every method in B-2.11 is unused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get the source code.

Assuming you're attempting to do this on Apache Flink:

[Source Code found here](https://github.com/apache/flink)

If you only want a particular folder from the source code, you can use the [method found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7106012/download-a-single-folder-or-directory-from-a-github-repo).