# PyCharm No usages found in Project Files

Tags: python, django, intellij-idea, pycharm

I've opened my Django project in PyCharm, as I want to use a proper IDE instead of a text editor to better manage the project.

When I run Find Usages on a function in `/projectroot/app/views.py` it says "No usages found in Project Files," but when I run <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> it finds 34 matches in 13 files.

As suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27634694/intellij-ultimate-14-find-usages-not-working) answer, I

1. marked `/projectroot/` directory as Sources Root
2. did File > Invalidate Caches / Restart...
3. in Find Options... I also tried to searching in All Places

If I run Find Usages on some other functions in `/projectroot/app/helpers.py` it seems to work.

Any ideas what else I could try?

[image]

Comment: Usages in PyCharm are - if i recall correctly - detected through imports, etc. But that does not mean it can not be imported for example through a string, etc. This is a consequence of the "hyperdynamic" nature of Python: it is impossible to determine *all* possible scenario's of usage.

Comment: Thanks, this helped a lot! I started to look through the imports and realised that when the function was used it was imported from somewhere else.